# Remove association with blank file extension?

Tags: windows-7, file-association, file-extension

The launcher for Mass Effect 2 mistakenly associates itself with files with no extension. The game's patch apparently fixes this, but it's too large for me to download on this connection. How do I fix this myself? It doesn't appear on Windows' "set associations" list. (Windows 7 x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it - ended up deleting `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Type` to fix this

Comment: this worked for me, except for the icons. (although I may need a reboot first, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

File associations are saved in the **`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`** (**`HKCR`**) branch of Registry<sup>1</sup>, and can be accessed through `regedit.exe`.

For extension-less files, **`HKCR\.`** seems to be used. If such a key exists, delete it (after exporting a backup copy, of course).

---

<sup>1</sup> which is in fact an union of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

Comment: Actually you'll need to delete it from both hkcu and hklm locations; If it exists in both, deleting the hkcr key won't do it. Luckily this can be done by navigating to the hkcr key, deleting it, then refreshing. If it reappears, delete it again.

Comment: Deleted, still opens in the ME2 launcher.

Comment: @Dataflashsabot: How about `HKCR\*` then?