# How to associate a command with files that have no extension (Regedit)

Tags: windows-registry, file-extension, file-association

I have several processes that generate files with no extension at all and would like to add a custom context menu menu (i.e. be able to right click on them and select 'open in Notepad' or 'make .txt file' etc)

I know I can associate (add) a command (e.g. "OpenNotepad") for a particular filetype (extension), or all filetypes...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\OpenNotepad]    ​      <--  All files/folders
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\Shell\OpenNotepad]    ​<-- .txt files
```

But how can I do this for files that have no extension?...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ ?? \Shell\OpenNotepad]      ​<--  Files with no extension?
```

Comment: Happy to provide an example, but don't want to get too side-tracked... So, for as example, Windows downloads Spotlight login page background images to: `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`. They are JPEG-format images (`.JPG`) but are stored as  extensionless-GUIDs (e.g. `2e2156afe6cf9fc53c0cd36177d1216ccb0986dbdea7183d6a337db055ec041b`)

Answer (score 1):

To add shell menu entries for files with no extension, use this registry branch:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\Shell]
```

**Example:**

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\Shell\OpenNotepad]
```

**References:**

- [How to Associate a Program with Files that have No Extension](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/associate-file-no-extension-program/)
- [windows 7 - Remove association with blank file extension? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/253592/remove-association-with-blank-file-extension/253644#253644)

Comment: Registry [export](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/File%20Associations/No%20Extension%20-%20Open%20with%20VScode.reg) for VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Doing so for text editors other than `NotePad` is slightly different due to whitespaces in the path:

- **[CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add):**

  1. **Open an Admin terminal:** <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `powershell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+OK
  2. ```reg
     # Associates no extension files with VS Code: (path must be double backslashed)
       # Quotes around %1 allow for files with whitespaces in names
       Reg Add 'HKCR\.\shell\open\command' /t REG_SZ /d '"C:\\Program Files\\VS Code\\Code.exe" "%1"'
     ```
- **GUI:**

  1. **Save as [`No-Ext Association.reg`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/File%20Associations/No-Ext%20Association%20(VS%20Code).reg):**

     ```reg
     Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

     [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]
     @=""

     [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell]

     [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell\open]

     [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell\open\command]
     @="\"C:\\Program Files\\VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
     ```
  2. **[Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import) into Registry via:**

     - Opening `No-Ext Association.reg` from Explorer
     - Admin terminal:

       ```reg
       Reg Import ".\No-Ext Association.reg"
       ```